# How to change the color of text?

Tags: html, css

Letting elements get shadowed everywhere is not a solution and this happens all the time with CSS. If we had kept `<font color="white">` it would have saved me an entire weekend.

Again I want to to something really simple and CSS makes it impossible to do something simple. All I want to do is to change the color of a text and I shouldn't be forced to ask a question here about it. CSS is wrongly designed when it makes an easy change impossible. All I want to do is make the link text of the button white:

[image]

I want the button to look more like this

[image]

I've made a http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/BGCJm/ with the problem that should not be difficult but time and time again it happens to me that I want to do something really simple like moving an element half an inch or changing a color and doing a really simple thing is impossible with a lot of CSS.

The HTML just looks like this

```
    <div id="post">
 <a href="/ai" id="ad">Post your ad for free</a>

</div>
```

Comment: honestly, if you can't change text color with css, then perhaps you should reconsider your career path... `<div id="post" style="color: white">`...

Comment: Keeping the anger out of your post and the non-related code out of your jsfiddle would make this question more useful to the community. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you just want `font color="white"` and that could have saved me an entire weekend. OF course I hate CSS and it's just right being angry about overengineering.

Comment: learn about selector, it's the basic tool and the whole power of css http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `#post a { color: white; }`. (ie, target the `a` child of the element with id=post)

[Forked Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XPjkq/)

CSS is frustrating, for sure, but there is a method to the madness.  I found it's worth reading articles on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) when I encounter difficulties.

Comment: Letting elements get shadowed everywhere is not a solution and this happens all the time with CSS. If we had kept `<font color="white">` it would have saved me an entire weekend.

Answer (score 1):

`#ad{color:white}` should solve your issue.